# Tiling an image over a page with ImageMagick with print margins?

Tags: pdf, svg, imagemagick, tile

I am trying to get ImageMagick to do something for me and I am running into a few problems. First, I am not understanding units of measure and such passed into ImageMagick and so my script is not producing what I need. Second, the way I am doing it is extremely inefficient. Running this script takes a very long time (the one you see below is slightly trimmed down from what I am running).

So to what I am doing... I have a number of svg files with icons in them. I am looking to generate a page for each of these files. The page generated will contain the icon tiled over the entire page with a margin on the side. I am looking for 1/2 inch tiles with 1/2 margins around the page which needs to be a US Letter (8 1/2 x 11 inch).

After reading a lot of the documentation this is what I came up with.

```
colors=(red blue purple yellow green black)

mkdir -p generated/icons/
for color in ${colors[@]}; do
  images=`printf "source/icons/${color}.svg%.0s " {1..300}`
  montage $images -tile 15x20 -page Letter+1+1 -units PixelsPerInch -density 2550x3300 \
                  generated/icons/${color}.pdf
done
```

So for each of my files I run montage. I use printf to repeat the image file name 300 times. I then tile this 15x20 times. 15x20 comes from 8.5 minus 1 inch margins = 7.5*2 = 15 and likewise (11-1)*2 = 20. 300 images come from 15*20. I then say I want this on a letter page offset 1x1. (This was my attempt at a margin) I say I am speaking in pixel per inch (but none of the units seem to match up). I set the dpi to 300 by the density command where 8.5*300 = 2550 and 11*300 = 3300.

I've been toying with other settings (geometry etc.) but none of these are working. And the units don't seem to make sense either... Right now my resultant pdf is a square etc...

How do I make tiled pages as such? Also is there a way for me to do this more efficiently? What I have thus far is very slow.

EDIT:

Some more information:

`i:montage --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-03-10 http://www.imagemagick.org`

tile image:[image]

my current output: [image]

Notice margins not right, is square not a letter page, also tiles as skewed

Comment: It would be very helpful for us to understand what you are trying to do if you provided one SVG file and a corresponding output example. Also what version of ImageMagick are you using. Tiling is more efficiently done using convert and reading the image once rather than so many times. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#tile for a number to tiling methods. I typically use the mpr: method.

Comment: @fmw42 added some images showing what I have at the moment.

Comment: Your input is a PNG and not an SVG. So we cannot start with your starting conditions. Can you post a link to the SVG file that corresponds to the PNG file you provided. What do you mean then tiled image is skewed? I do not see that.

Comment: Are you using RSVG or Inkscape or IM MSVG/XML for you SVG delegate reader and what version? Note that your IM version is about 100 versions old. You might want to consider upgrading, if things do not work properly.

Comment: What output density do you want for your result? That will determine your quality. For example, if your tile corresponds to 0.5 inches at 72 dpi, then the tile is 0.5*72=36 pixels. But if you want 300 dpi, then 0.5*300=150 pixels per tile.

Comment: P.S. You can find your delegate and version using convert -list format and seeing what it says for SVG

Comment: Sorry just got back around to this. Stackoverflow didn't let me upload the svg so I uploaded a png conversion of it. I used your answer below and it works just with the svg as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the PNG image you provided, and I presume you want a 1 inch border of white all around inside an 8.5x11 inch printed image. Thus the tiled width would be 7.5 inches and tiled height would be 10 inches.

- 1 in = 300 dpi so border thickness = 300 px = 2 tiles thick
- 11-1 = 10 inches tall for tiled region height = 10*300 = 3000 px
- 8.5-1 = 7.5 inches wide for tiled region width = 7.5*300 = 2250 px
- 1 tile = 0.5 inches at 300 dpi = 0.5*300 = 150 px

---

```
convert lUDbK.png -resize "150x150!" -write mpr:tile +delete -size 2250x3000 tile:mpr:tile -bordercolor white -border 300 -units pixelsperinch -density 300 tiled_page.png
```

Time to process was 1.75 sec on my Mac Mini.

This produces an image which is rather large. You will have to extract the image to see the border, since this page background is white.

[image]

(Note that PNG only supports pixelspercentimeter, but IM converts my specification of pixelperinch accordingly. So if you look at the meta data, it will probably show you some other density in units of pixelspercentimeter. But they will correspond to the desired 300 dpi.)

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted. I made a slight adjustment as I just wanted 1/2 border so it would fit on one page. likewise the performance is acceptable.